# How to extract terms of specific data constructor from a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

A common problem I got in Haskell is to extract all terms in a list belonging to a specific data constructor and I'm wondering if there are any better ways than the way I'm doing it at the moment.

Let's say you got

```
data Foo = Bar | Goo
```

, the list

```
foos = [Bar, Goo, Bar, Bar, Goo]
```

and wish to extract all `Goo`s from `foos`. At the moment I usually do something like

```
goos = [Goo | Goo <- foos]
```

and all is well. The problem is when `Goo` got a bunch of fields and I'm forced to write something like

```
goos = [Goo a b c d e f | Goo a b c d e f <- foos]
```

which is far from ideal. How you do usually handle this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Seems like there are two parts to this question:

1. Is there an easier way to do pattern matching
2. Are list comprehensions ok here?

Firstly, there **is** a better way to match on fields you don't care about:

```
goos = [ x | x@(Goo {}) <- foos]
```

Secondly, using list comprehensions is a perfectly cromulent way of writing these kinds of filters. For example, in the base library, catMaybes is defined as:

```
catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
catMaybes ls = [x | Just x <- ls]
```

(from the base library). So that idiom is fine.

Comment: But OP wants something similar to `[Just x | Just x <- ls]`, not `catMaybes` or `rights`.

Comment: That's fine, the question is in two parts: whether list comprehensions are ok, and secondly, what form of pattern matching. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
[x | x@(Goo _ _ _ _ _ _) <- foos]
```

You could also define a

```
isGoo :: Foo -> Bool
isGoo (Goo _ _ _ _ _ _) = True
isGoo _ = False
```

and then use `filter`

```
filter isGoo foos
```

or

```
[x | x <- foos, isGoo]
```